# Silent notifications not working iOS Firebase

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, push-notification

When sending silent-notifications from firebase-admin cloud sdk (from firebase functions), I can see it is received since my console is printing some cryptic message but doens't actually run the logic in the method.

Here is the payload being sent:

```
 message.apns = {
          payload: {
            aps : {
              'content-available' : true
            }
          },
          data: {
            text: 'message'
          }
        };
```

Here is the log being printed in my console (my device is connected to my computer and running xcode on debug).

```
2020-03-18 20:07:44.687628+0200[2434:580744] [] nw_read_request_report [C3] Receive failed with error "Software caused connection abort"
2020-03-18 20:07:44.687895+0200[2434:580744] [] nw_read_request_report [C2] Receive failed with error "Software caused connection abort"
2020-03-18 20:07:44.690177+0200[2434:580744] [] nw_read_request_report [C3] Receive failed with error "Software caused connection abort"
```

However, it seems like something is blocking it from actually working and calling the relevant app delegate methods.

Has anyone run into this issue before?

Super cryptic and not really sure how to handle.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you solved this issue?

Comment: nope..i ended up sunsetting from the project. Will check if the other dev fixed it @lithium